# Why does Thymeleaf tell me: "Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/", althogh there is actually a folder

Tags: java, spring, maven, thymeleaf

As you can see `src/main/resource/templates`:
[image: exists.]

However, thymeleaf tells me:

```
"Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/"
```

This problem can be fixed  by changing it to:
[image: change]

Change the corresponding directory from `"Excluded: **"` to `"Excluded: None"`.

But I don't like this solution, because it fixes the problem only temporarily. As soon as I update the maven project, everything is set back to the old values.
I've already seen another Spring Boot projects, that run fine without changing the class path.